# How to access user uid from anywhere in the code?

Tags: python

I'm trying to access the currently logged in user eslewhere in my code (i.e in other classes). I've managed to do this to some extent with `global` (frowned upon I know but didn't find any other way), as shown below:

````
class Login(Screen):

    def login(self, email, password):
        try:
            global user
            user = auth.sign_in_with_email_and_password(email, password)
            print(user['localId']) #This is the users uid 


class SelectChat(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SelectChat, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        grid = GridLayout(cols=1)
        self.add_widget(grid)

        docs = db.collection(u'users').where(u'value', u'==', True).stream()

        for doc in docs: # cycle through database and create Buttons for each value found
            dict = doc.to_dict()
            btn = Button(text="{} {}".format(dict['first_name'], dict['last_name']), id=doc.id)
            btn.bind(on_release=self.move_to_chat(doc.id))
            grid.add_widget(btn)

    def move_to_chat(self, *args):
        group_id = str(user['localId']) + str(doc.id) # This is where I'm trying to access the user variable but it's getting called on startup due to the above ```btn.bind()``` call.
        print(group_id)
        MDApp.get_running_app().sm.current = "chat"
````

The problem I'm having now is that I want to access the `user['localId']` value in the `__init__` method of another class. As this is run when as soon as the app has loaded the `login` method hasn't started and therefore there's no `user` variable.

Error message: `NameError: name 'user' is not defined`

Comment: You need to rethink your design to make the `user` available where needed. It is something that is hard to help with in this platform especially with the information given. For example, we don't know how is the `Screen` class or what is the relation between `SelectChat` and `Login`

Comment: Ok, is it better practice to put all the logic in the ```App``` class, rather than the various ```Screen``` classes?

Comment: I don't know what is the `App` class so I can't say. Generally speaking, from what I can tell here, you might want to simply pass the `user` as an argument to the related functions of `Screen` that require a specific user

Comment: But the user variable hasn't been created when the ```SelectChat``` class runs. I can't create the user variable until the user has entered their username and password on the login screen, however

Comment: My point exactly, something seems to be wrong with the design... If the user is not created yet, how can be that `SelectChat` is trying to use it?

Comment: Yes, I suppose I was partly hoping someone would say I can do something other than ```btn.bind``` to set the ```on_release``` property as this is what's causing me the issue. If there wasn't a workaround for this I thought I'd need to put my ```login``` logic in the ```App``` class so I can access the ```user``` variable